# Open the first child when the page loads

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

Here is my accordion [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/a545y/15/). I need first child element to be opened by default.

Code used

```
    $('h3','.horizontalaccordion ul li').on('click',function() {
    $(this).closest('li').toggleClass('hover').siblings().removeClass('hover');
});​
```

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel ? Since you are using JQuery already, consider using JQuery UI Accordion ? http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion :)

Comment: I am using horizontal accordion and also my accordion requirement is bit complicated according to the dynamic implementation so I have used the different one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will this do...

```
$('h3','.horizontalaccordion ul li').on('click',function() {
    $(this).closest('li').toggleClass('hover').siblings().removeClass('hover');
});

$('.horizontalaccordion ul li:first').addClass('hover');
```

​

Comment: No problem. I would agree with @Endy in saying that you might want to have a look at http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/

Answer (score 3):

On your **html**. Add class `hover` to the first `li`.

```
<div class="horizontalaccordion">
    <ul>
        <li class="hover">
            <h3>Heading 1</h3>
            <div>Content For Panel 1.</div>
        </li>
        ...
    </ul>
</div>
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ricardolohmann/a545y/27/)

Answer (score 0):

just call the click event

```
$('h3','.horizontalaccordion ul li:first-child').click();
```

​
See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gajjuthechamp/a545y/28/) http://jsfiddle.net/gajjuthechamp/a545y/28/

I just added last link in JavaScript section